# HIbernate C3p0 connection pooling: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

We are using **hibernate 3** and **c3p0-0.9.1**. We have an Hibernate criteria based query to check the keyed in username and password from database tables as well as other queries.

We are facing the connection reset issue with SQLState as null randomly. If provide the details again in the page, everything is working fine for some time. If we try after some time, again the same problem for the first time and when re-enter the username and password, it is working fine for sometime. Please find the below error messages for reference.

> 00:12:42 WARN [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter:77
>   logExceptions] - SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: null 00:12:42 ERROR
>   [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter:78 logExceptions] - Io
>   exception: Connection reset

When I execute the generated query in oracle client such as SQL developer, able to get the result. Just to understand the actual problem, updated the above Java code to make use of HibernateTemplate and noticed the exception as below:

> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query

When i run through the application, facing this issue randomly.

In one more website, I read something like: if there are no transactions executed upto some time (till idle time out of database), the connection will be invalidated which causes this issue. If that is the case, is there any way to reconnect to oracle using the configuration.

In mySQL, autoReconnect is there. Is there anything like that for Oracle?

Can anyone please assist? I really appreciate any help in this regard. Thanks.

Best Regards, Lucky

Comment: When you speak about user name and password, you mean those of the database user, not an application user?

Comment: it's helpful to log full Exceptions (including especially root cause Exceptions) and provide some config. on the c3p0-side, two obvious things: 1) upgrade, c3p0-0.9.1 is very, very old, never versions are drop-in replacements; and 2) configure Connection testing, see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing or more simply http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#simple_advice_on_connection_testing